# Could we consider reopening this Yu-Gi-Oh Question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

I edited this question and now it's clearer what it is asking: [Can I play Yu-Gi-Oh! with only level 5 or higher cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/43716/22373)

I voted to reopen, and would like to ask the Community to consider voting as well.

Answer (score 2):

This question reached 5 votes and was reopened :)

Thank you for taking it into consideration.